# Appending tags in OCI using SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdk, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions

I have namespace already created and defined tags to resources. When I try adding new tags to the resources, the old tags are getting deleted.
As I would like to use the old data and return the value along with the new tags. Please help me with how I can achieve this.

**get volume details from a specific compartment**

```
import oci

config = oci.config.from_file("~/.oci/config")

core_client = oci.core.BlockstorageClient(config)

get_volume_response = core_client.get_volume(
    volume_id="ocid1.test.oc1..<unique_ID>EXAMPLE-volumeId-Value")

# Get the data from response
print(get_volume_response.data)
```

**output**

```
{
  "availability_domain": "eto:PHX-AD-1",
  "compartment_id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaapmj",
  "defined_tags": {
    "OMCS": {
      "CREATOR": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    "Oracle-Tags": {
      "CreatedBy": "xyz@gmail.com",
      "CreatedOn": "2022-07-5T08:29:24.865Z"
    }
  },
  "display_name": "test_VG",
  "freeform_tags": {},
  "id": "ocid1.volumegroup.oc1.phx.abced",
  "is_hydrated": null,
  "lifecycle_state": "AVAILABLE",
  "size_in_gbs": 100,
  "size_in_mbs": 102400,
  "source_details": {
    "type": "volumeIds",
    "volume_ids": [
      "ocid1.volume.oc1.phx.xyz"
    ]
  }
```

I want the API below to update the tag along with the old data.

***old tag***

```
"defined_tags": {
    "OMCS": {
      "CREATOR": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    "Oracle-Tags": {
      "CreatedBy": "xyz@gmail.com",
      "CreatedOn": "2022-07-5T08:29:24.865Z"
```

```
import oci

config = oci.config.from_file("~/.oci/config")
core_client = oci.core.BlockstorageClient(config)

update_volume_response = core_client.update_volume(
    volume_id="ocid1.test.oc1..<unique_ID>EXAMPLE-volumeId-Value",
    update_volume_details=oci.core.models.UpdateVolumeDetails(
        defined_tags={
            'OMCS':{
                'INSTANCE': 'TEST',
                'COMPONENT': 'temp1.mt.exy.vcn.com'
            }
        },
        display_name = "TEMPMT01"))


print(update_volume_response.data)
```

I also tried but got an attribute error.

```
for tag in get_volume_response.data:
  def_tag.appened(tag.defined_tags)
return (def_tag)
```

Please help on how can I append the defined_tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tags` are defined as `dict` in `OCI`. Append works the same way as in appending `dict`.

Below I have pasted the code for updating the `defined_tags` for `Block Volumes` in `OCI`

```
import oci
from oci.config import from_file

configAPI = from_file()  # Config file is read from user's home location i.e., ~/.oci/config

core_client = oci.core.BlockstorageClient(configAPI)

get_volume_response = core_client.get_volume(
    volume_id="ocid1.volume.oc1.ap-hyderabad-1.ameen")

# Get the data from response
volume_details = get_volume_response.data

defined_tags = getattr(volume_details, "defined_tags")
freeform_tags = getattr(volume_details, "freeform_tags")


# Add new tags as required. As defined_tags is a dict, addition of new key/value pair works like below.
# In case there are multiple tags to be added then use update() method of dict.
defined_tags["OMCS"]["INSTANCE"] = "TEST"
defined_tags["OMCS"]["COMPONENT"] = "temp1.mt.exy.vcn.com"

myJson={"freeform_tags":freeform_tags,"defined_tags": defined_tags}


update_volume_response = core_client.update_volume(
    volume_id="ocid1.volume.oc1.ap-hyderabad-1.ameen",
    update_volume_details=oci.core.models.UpdateVolumeDetails(
        defined_tags=defined_tags,
        freeform_tags=freeform_tags))

print(update_volume_response.data)
```